# Permutation vectors with unknowns in Sage

Tags: python, sage

I'm trying to do some work with Sage, and I can't understand how to do the following.

I've written some little code:

```
def ElementDr1(r):
    G = SymmetricGroup(r)
    E = G.list()
    O = G.order()
    coeff = ZeroCoeff(O)

    for i in range(0,O):
        if E[i] == G("(1,r)"): 
            coeff [i]=1
        if E[i] == G("(2,3)*(1,r)"):
            coeff [i]=1
        if E[i] == G("(1,3)*(1,r)"):
            coeff [i]=-1
    return coeff
```

and Sage says that the permutation vector `(1,r)` is invalid. I'm sure there must be a way to write permutation vectors with unknowns, but I can't find what this method is by looking at the Sage help.

Comment: Hello, when I paste in your code, I get no error for defining the function. When I try to use it, by typing for example `ElementDr1(3)`, I get `NameError: global name 'ZeroCoeff' is not defined`. Can you provide a minimal working example to illustrate the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues here:

1. The syntax for creating an element from cycle decomposition is `G("(1,2)(3,4)")` with no * in between.
2. The cycles must be disjoint, i.e., no element can appear twice. You have 1 appearing twice.
3. Using r inside a string instead of substituting: Samuel Lelièvre commented on that already.

Since (1,3)(1,r) is not a valid cycle decomposition, what you want to do is to multiply (1,3) by (1,r). To this end, create these elements first and **then** multiply them (using * operator). Since the elements are cycles, you don't even need a string: an element can be created from a tuple.

```
def ElementDr1(r):
    G = SymmetricGroup(r)
    E = G.list()
    O = G.order()
    coeff = [0 for i in range(0,O)]  # self-contained examples are good

    for i in range(0,O):
        if E[i] == G((1,r)):
            coeff[i] = 1
        if E[i] == G((2,3))*G((1,r)):
            coeff[i] = 1
        if E[i] == G((1,3))*G((1,r)):
            coeff[i] = -1
    return coeff
```

Now it runs, outputting, for example, `[-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]` with r=3.

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely due to calling `G("...")` with strings containing `r`. Replace `r` by its value in these strings, for example as follows:

```
def ElementDr1(r):
    G = SymmetricGroup(r)
    E = G.list()
    O = G.order()
    coeff = ZeroCoeff(O)

    for i in range(0,O):
        if E[i] == G("(1,%s)"%r): 
            coeff[i] = 1
        if E[i] == G("(2,3)*(1,%s)"%r):
            coeff[i] = 1
        if E[i] == G("(1,3)*(1,%s)"%r):
            coeff[i] = -1
    return coeff
```

Comment: Thanks but for some reason that still doesn't work, this time sage says `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple''. Any idea why? Also sorry for not making it clear, but ZeroCoeff(n) just creates an $n$-tuple of zeroes.